# Pytest AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'test_func'

Tags: python, pytest, python-3.7

I'm trying to test python function using `pytest` but get this error.

```
import pytest

class Example:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def test_func(list_arg):
        return len(list_arg)


@pytest.fixture()
def example_instance():
    return Example()


def test_util_fun():
    empty_val = []

    assert example_instance.test_func(empty_val) == 2
```

error :

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'test_func'
```

pytest and python versions

```
python 3.7
pytest 4.5.0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass `example_instance` as an argument to `test_util_fun`; it doesn't magically appear just because it's a fixture:

```
def test_util_fun(example_instance):
    empty_val = []

    assert example_instance.test_func(empty_val) == 2
```

The rules for `pytest` fixtures are a bit different. If you leave it out, then `example_instance` will bind to the *function object* itself.

However, if you specify it as an argument, `pytest` will automatically instantiate the fixture when required, according to the specified scope, and pass it to the test function.